# How to use $out in Meteor for aggregation?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I can succeed using loop over the results and adding each document by `this.added` to do aggregation.

However, when I tried to use `$out` way, I failed. My client side got 0 results.

```
Meteor.publish('anotherCollection', function () {
  OneCollection.aggregate([
    // some pipelines here,
    { $out: 'anotherCollection' }
  ]);

  this.ready();
}
```

I am using Meteor 1.3.2.4 with meteorhacks:aggregate package. My mongo version is 2.6 which should support `$out`.

How can I use `$out` way correctly in Meteor? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't that publish method need to return something?

Comment: @RobertMoskal My understanding is that `$out` did the `this.added`'s work. But since `this.added` is Meteor's API while `$out` belongs to Mongo. So maybe that is why I cannot get results?

Comment: @RobertMoskal thank you toooo!! you pointed out the error too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move the result of the aggregation to `annotherCollection` and publish that.

So your usage of [aggregate](https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-aggregate/blob/master/index.js) and [$out](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/) is correct but 
[publishers](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/publish-and-subscribe) need to return a cursor so you need `return (annotherCollecitonVar.find())`